# Fixed position inside a div Css

Tags: html, css

I need to arrange some element inside a div. The problem is that I can't modify `html` code, so I need to resolve it by `css`.

I have these blog posts:
[image]

The problem is that the 'Read more' button is shifted down when the title or the content is too long. I need the button to be fixed at bottom of the blog post, as it is in the second post.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<div class="contact_con blog-posts">

    <div class="loop-entry-thumbnail">
    <a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/the-magic-of-viceland/" title="The Magic of Viceland">
      <img src="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/wp-content/uploads/The-Magic-of-Viceland.jpg" alt="The Magic of Viceland" title="The Magic of Viceland" width="100%">
         </a>
         </div>
  <div class="loop-entry-content clr">
      <header>
       <h2 class="loop-entry-title entry-title">
        <a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/the-magic-of-viceland/">The Magic of Viceland...</a>
       </h2>
      </header>
     <div class="loop-entry-excerpt entry clr blog_loop_entry_title">
         I’m part of a generation that rarely watches traditional cable news, and instead ab...<br>
      <span class="home_readmore home_readmore_button"><a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/the-magic-of-viceland/">Read more</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>

       </div>
```

I have tried with position: absolute and relative, but it not resolved this problem.

Comment: **home_readmore_button** to absolute, bottom 10px, right 10px, and **loop-entry-thumbnail** in position relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should limit the height of the `loop-entry-content`, then the absolute position will be OK:

```css
.blog-posts {
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
}
.loop-entry-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.home_readmore {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact_con blog-posts">

    <div class="loop-entry-thumbnail">
    <a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/the-magic-of-viceland/" title="The Magic of Viceland">
      <img src="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/wp-content/uploads/The-Magic-of-Viceland.jpg" alt="The Magic of Viceland" title="The Magic of Viceland" width="100%">
         </a>
         </div>
  <div class="loop-entry-content clr">
      <header>
       <h2 class="loop-entry-title entry-title">
        <a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/the-magic-of-viceland/">The Magic of Viceland...</a>
       </h2>
      </header>
     <div class="loop-entry-excerpt entry clr blog_loop_entry_title">
         I’m part of a generation that rarely watches traditional cable news, and instead ab and instead ab and instead ab...<br>
      <span class="home_readmore home_readmore_button"><a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/the-magic-of-viceland/">Read more</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>

       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a height in your content class "loop-entry-content", so your button will stay in a fixed position

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this CSS

```
.loop-entry-content{
position:relative;
max-height:{{some desired height}};
}
.home-readmore-button{
position:absolute;
bottom: 10px;
right:10px;
}
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

**You can use flex box CSS to the parent element( parent or your named class ). This will resolve the height problem.**

```
.parent
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

<div class="parent">
  <div class="contact_con blog-posts">

  </div>
</div>
```